# Jackson won't parse XML file to JSON entirely

Tags: java, json, jackson, modelmapper

I'm trying to parse an xml string into JSON using Jackson.

At the moment I'm using this string:

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                " <rootNode>\n" +
                "    <data>\n" +
                "        <cityCode>R8</cityCode>\n" +
                "        <place>\n" +
                "            <code>01</code>\n" +
                "        </place>\n" +
                "    </data>\n" +
                "    <data>\n" +
                "        <cityCode>R9</cityCode>\n" +
                "        <place>\n" +
                "            <code>02</code>\n" +
                "        </place>\n" +
                "    </data>\n" +
                "</rootNode>";
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
JsonNode node = xmlMapper.readTree(xml);
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(node)
```

But the parser only seems to get one node:

```
{"data":{"cityCode":"R9","place":{"code":"02"}}}
```

How can I get all the nodes converted into JSON?

Thank you

Comment: The two data-xml-elements get converted to json-elements with the name "data". It seems you can't have two json-elements with the same name in one json-object. The second data-element therefor overwrites the first one.

Comment: Read https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml#known-limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get it working using `readValue` into a `List`

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
List list = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, List.class);
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(list);
```

Not sure why your version does not work, there seem to be issues with `readTree` and repeated attributes. See [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-convert-xml-json), point `5.1. Limitations`